# How to add a watermark to ms-word with Default \ Auto settings

Tags: .net, interop, office-interop, office-addins, word-addins

I am trying in .Net using office interop to add watermark to a word document.
I would like the text to be with these settings as shown here;

[image]

With emphasis on how to set Size = Auto, and Semitransparent == true?

Right now I use Shapes.AddTextEffect but this requires manually defining the font Size and Fill.Transparency with exact values.

I also tries to perform `TextFrame.AutoSize = MsoAutoSize.msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape` but it didn't seem to actually change the font size.

So, how do I add a watermark text with the above settings? Thanks.

Comment: If you record a macro in Word when performing these actions, then run that macro does it give the correct result? If it does, you can compare what the macro does to what your code does and adjust. When it works, that's the best way to figure out this kind of problem. If you then need more support, please use the [edit] link under your question to add 1) the code you have and 2) the code from the macro recorder.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thank you for this great technique! I will try to implement this macro-based code tomorrow.